# Can excel launch .bat file? (VBA, macro etc)

Tags: excel, vba

How I can launch a `.bat` file from [excel](/questions/tagged/excel)? For example via an event or a button?

And is it possible to build a `.bat` file into Excel? For example, I build a launchable `.bat` file from Excel, a user downloads my Excel file from a server, and then this Excel file can launch the `.bat` file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Running a bat file**

To call a `.bat` file from vba, you can use the `shell` function:

```
Sub test()
    Call Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") & " /c C:\Path.bat", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

*Note:* the /c closes the DOS prompt when finished.

**Creating a .bat file from Excel**

You can create a file (a `.bat` or whatever) with VBA so it could be a txt, a bat or a log file, code is seemingly the same.

Here are some links to begin with:

- [create a log file](http://www.exceltip.com/st/Log_files_using_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/493.html)
- [exporting a text file](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ImpText.aspx) from Chip Pearson
- [read file](http://www.exceluser.com/explore/questions/vba_textcols.htm)

Comment: thanks for info. And is there any way to append .bat file to excel file?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: because I want run ETL proces from excel file. And I want all users can download excel from server and run ETL from it

Answer (score 1):

Think of the `.xlsx` file as a `.zip` archive. This archive houses the various *XML* components that build up the Excel file. Note that VBA exposes a special container to work with your custom *XML* code, through the  `CustomXMLPart` object.

I once stored thumbnails in encoded XML inside an `.xlsx` file, so storing any text file such as your `.bat` should be no problem at all.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608612.aspx) shows you how to work with `CustomXMLPart` object from VSTO. Working directly from VBA should be similar.